# Serializing HashMap And writing Into a file

Tags: java, hashmap, file-writing

I have a `HashMap` which contains `Set<String>` as Key and Value,

```
HashMap<Set<String>, Set<String>> mapData = new HashMap<Set<String>, Set<String>>();
```

If I want to write this `HashMap` object into a file, Whats is the best way to do it. Also I want to read this back from that file as `HashMap<Set<String>, Set<String>>`.

Comment: why on earth having a `Set` as a key?

Comment: And for the question: have a look at *Serialization*

Comment: @lino Sometimes you may need Set as key. In my usecase there is no other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I write a map to file and read it back from the file. You can adapt it for your usecase.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> deSerializeHashMap() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/opt/hashmap.ser");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Map<String, Integer> map = (Map<String, Integer>) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    System.out.printf("De Serialized HashMap data  saved in hashmap.ser");
    return map;
}

public static void serializeHashMap(Map<String, Integer> hmap) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/opt/hashmap.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(hmap);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
    System.out.printf("Serialized HashMap data is saved in hashmap.ser");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if you really want to do this but using serialization it is as simple like that:

```
try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(yourFile)))
{
   out.writeObject(map);
}
```